# How to change or overwrite input password

Tags: python-3.x, input

How do I change password in python ? I tried to change the password but it uses the initial password. How do I implement the new password into the code.

```
def password():
    pw = input("Enter Password: ")
    if pw == initial_pw:
        print("Initializing....")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("Access Denied! Wrong Password!")
        password()

def Setting():
     pw = input("Enter Old Password: ")
     if pw == initial_pw:
         new_pw = input("Enter New Password: ")
         print (new_pw)
         print ("Password has been changed.")
     else:
         print ("Sorry, you have just entered an invalid password.")
         Setting()

initial_pw = input("Create New Password: ")
print("Create Successful.")
while True:
    password()

    print("Press 1 to change password")
    choice = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    if choice == 1:
        Setting()
```

Comment: When and why would you want to change it?

Comment: I want the user to be able to change password to have a more secure system. This password is basically to prevent intruders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the password from `Setting()`, and assign it to the new password:

```
import time

def password():
    pw = input("Enter Password: ")
    if pw == initial_pw:
        print("Initializing....")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("Access Denied! Wrong Password!")
        password()

def Setting():
     pw = input("Enter Old Password: ")
     if pw == initial_pw:
         new_pw = input("Enter New Password: ")
         print (new_pw)
         print ("Password has been changed.")
     else:
         print ("Sorry, you have just entered an invalid password.")
         Setting()
     try:
         return new_pw
     except UnboundLocalError:
         return pw

initial_pw = input("Create New Password: ")
print("Create Successful.")
while True:
    password()

    print("Press 1 to change password")
    choice = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    if choice == 1:
        initial_pw = Setting()
```

**I would also suggest using the `get pass` module if you care about password security.** It prevents character echo:

```
>>> password = input('Enter your password: ')
Enter your password: mypassword
>>> password
'mypassword'
>>> import getpass
>>> password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password: ')
Enter your password: 
>>> password
'mypassword'
>>>
```

Comment: The moment I enter my password wrong during pw = input("Enter Old Password: "), I will get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_pw' referenced before assignment. How do I fix this ?

Comment: oh thanks, I try put global new_pw and it works too. Thanks for you help anyway. Much appreciated